# Store command output in variable

Tags: linux, environment-variables

If I do `z='ls'` and then `echo $z` it will print the directory I listed, but without newlines or formatting. I assume lack of colored formatting is impossible to get around, but would it be possible to get it with the newlines in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the variable:

```
echo "$z"
```

Without quotes each word in `$z` becomes a separate argument to `echo`, with quotes the whole variable is a single argument - newlines and all.

Comment: Just so. The variable contains the line feeds, but when passed as a parameter list to any command (internal or external) all white spaces are treated equally as parameter delimiters. The double-quotes mean that only a single is passed, with all its internal formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can get color by saying

```
z=$(ls --color)
```

or, to be explicit,

```
x=$(ls --color=always)
```

`$(command)` is (essentially) equivalent to `` `command` ``;
see [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/3960947) 
`ls`’s default is `--color=auto`, which means use color only when writing to a terminal
(i.e., when the standard output is a terminal). 
`$(command)` and `` `command` `` run the *`command`* with output to a pipe; `--color=always` tells `ls` to use color even in this case.

You can test this easily by comparing

```
ls | cat
```

with

```
ls --color | cat
```